# Deploying Django at Dreamhost

Tags: django, deployment, fastcgi, wsgi, dreamhost

I'm trying to get the Poll tutorial working at my Dreamhost account (I don't have any prior experience of deploying Django). I downloaded the script I found here (http://gabrielfalcao.com/2008/12/02/hosting-and-deploying-django-apps-on-dreamhost/) at my home directory and executed it. Now I have Python 2.5 and Django in ~/.myroot/ and my Django projects directory is ~/projects/

Here's the content of ~/projects/ directory (I copied the polls/ and and templates/polls/ directories myself).

```
projects/
|-- admin_media -> /home/imran2140/.myroot/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
|-- dispatch.fcgi
|-- polls
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- polls.db
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- script_templates
|   |-- dispatch.template
|   `-- htaccess.template
`-- templates
    `-- polls
        |-- detail.html
        |-- index.html
        `-- results.html

5 directories, 17 files
```

Now what should I do to get the Polls app working?

**Update**

I finally got a "Hello World" Django app working with Passanger WSGI. It worked fine with both Server's default Python 2.3.5 and my installed Python 2.5.2.

[Passanger WSGI - Django](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger_WSGI) at Dreamhost Wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since DreamHost supports mod_passenger, and AFAIK it works not only for Ruby/Rails apps but also for Python/Django - you might give it a try.

Just put app there and select directory where execute script are (eg. dispatch.fcgi).
You might wanna see/study [a working example](http://github.com/kwe/passenger-django-wsgi-example/tree/django) at GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a script that you can run that does most of the set up for you. It is mentioned on the main page about Django on the Dreamhost wiki here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django

Answer (score 1):

This is the official [Dreamhost wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Django). I don't know what the script, you mention, is doing, but you have to setup rewrite rules in `.htaccess` to run your fcgi scripts.

But it is much more easier to setup Django on any VPS host than on shared hosting. Consider also their disclaimer:

> If Django is crucial to your site, you may wish to consider another host since **Dreamhost does not officially support Django**. In the past, some users have reported reliablity problems; however, others have had no problems.

Comment: Please check the link in question. It describes what it does (I got it from Dreamhost wiki). As for no official support, I'm not really concerned if I can get it working.

Comment: Just because they don't officially support it doesn't mean you should consider looking elsewhere.

Comment: Sure. Just because some users reported reliability problems is a more important reason to look elsewhere. That phrase seems to be removed from the wiki now, BTW. This is the old version: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php?title=Django&oldid=24848

Comment: *Nothing* is supported on a VPS - you do it all yourself. I think Dreamhost means is that they won't give you free help, and if they change their underlying systems in a way that causes you grief they don't want to get used. I'm guessing they got a lot of tech suport questions from people who needed help setting it up, and decided not to help. They do maintain the OS, database, and Apache though.

Comment: @wisty I was talking about their shared hosting (two years ago), I don't remember a VPS offer back then.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through it with dreamhost, and I decided it was simply too much trouble to set up Django.

> But it is much more easier to setup Django on any VPS host than on shared hosting.

I've had good luck with [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/).  They're not a VPS but they still give you a lot of control over your site (like you can set up your own Apache instance if you want).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely consider webfaction if I have to switch from Dreamhost. They seem quite affordable for a quality Django host.

Answer (score 1):

Passenger is the way to go. I wrote a little [HOWTO on building a modern (2.6.5) Python and configuring Django, etc. with Passenger](http://chester.blog.br/archives/2010/04/howto-python-2-6-5-django-via-passenger-wsgi-at-dreamhost.html), it may be helpful if you already have a project.